# store === characters in database for empty data while processing xml file

Tags: java, mysql, xml, jakarta-ee, jaxb

Hi am parsing an xml file through JAXB and saving the data in the database table and am able to do this appropriately. My question is if the xml file returns an empty data for a particular field it should display as === in the database table. How can I do this while processing the xml file.
The xml file has two nodes, abc and xyz and the xml file should contain any one of these.There are two coloumns available in the database say name and version. these two coloumns will be derived by comparing the abc and xyz nodes of teh xml file in the database by using a common id and fetch the values for name and title. Can some one please help me in understanding how to handle this by processing the xml file.

I Wish I could post the code, but the code is too huge to post it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking sounds weird, but assuming your data is a `String`, you could do this:

```
if (data == null || data.isEmpty())
{
    data = "===";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the tags on your question you appear to have two steps in your processing:

1. XML to object using JAXB
2. object to database using ?

I would put the logic for storing `===` in the database as part of the `object-to-database` processing.  If you are using JPA 2.1 (part of Java EE 7) you could look at JPA converters to encapsulate this logic.